# Build .framework in XCode 6

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, xcode6

I started to use XCode 6 since the 4th beta and now I was trying to create and export a pure Swift .framework for iOS.

I have to admin I am encountering a lot of issues in doing it. I want to export the .framework as universal, so I can run it on both, device and simulator.

Now, my question is, is there a way to accomplish it?
I tried to build and archive, to export the .framework product merging the 2 results with `lipo`, etc... and the Apple documentation seems incomplete.

The single result I got is a .framework immediately rising an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using one of the declared objects, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the framework by using the script below.

1) You create new aggregate target in your framework project.

2) Add Run Script in Build Phases.

3) Copy the below script and paste.

4) choose Aggregate with target type as iOS Device and Run .

5) you can now use the combined framework.

```
FRAMEWORK_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME}"

SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator | echo

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -sdk iphoneos -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -target ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos | echo

rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"

cp -r "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/." "${FRAMEWORK}"

lipo "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" -create -output"${FRAMEWORK}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}" | echo
```

Comment: karthikeyan viswanathan, combining the frameworks with your script will not work properly (at least for Swift Framework). It's necessary also to copy the files of the swiftmodule (in Modules directory) of -iphonesimulator to the swiftmodule of universal framework directory.